# How to check if an item is in another item's ManyToMany field?

Tags: django

In Django, I am interested in checking if an item is in another item's ManyToMany field. How can I do that?

Answer (score 17):

Set the [related_name](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name) attribute.

If object Egg has a ManyToManyField pointing to Spam, and you set the related name to `egg_set`, you can access the eggs via `Spam.egg_set.all()` (or use `filter()` to get a specific egg as shown below).

So to check if the Spam object `my_spam` has the Egg with the ID 42, you could do something like:

```
if my_spam.egg_set.filter(pk=42):
    fry_bacon()
```